# how to customize Registration form

Tags: forms, users

How to add a fields into custom registration form in drupal7 and how to give the link so that annonmous user can register.

Answer (score 0):

As an adminstrator, you can set additional user fields at:

*/admin/config/people/accounts*

Note the tabs **Manage fields** and **Manage displays**. You can control if and how these fields appear on the registration form, and also how they appear to the user via these tabs. You can even create non-visible fields for storing other kinds of hidden data against a user should you need to.

By default, the link to register is:

*user/register*

You would normally create a menu item if one doesn't exist already to appear somewhere on your site, or you can just output the link in a suitable location depending on your needs.